# crm online, add organisations

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

Is there any posibility to add more organizations to "CRM 2011 Online" like it has been realized in "CRM on permise" (with assistent or something like this)? I just want to get an array with multiple organizations by calling CrmDiscoveryService

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, if you purchase a new subscription/licence.

An alternative would be to add new Business Units under one organisation.

Comment: It would be great just to add new Business Units, but they are not through CrmDiscoveryService obtainable

Comment: Ok, i schould just register new account WITH THE SAME live id